date incorrectly stored in MariaDB
My output date 1988-00-00 differs from my input date 2012-12-12 and I cannot figure out why?
I am inserting the date 2012-12-12, which sits in variable $_SESSION[CompletionDate], into a MariaDB table with the following php script:
echo"<p>CompletionDate = ".$_SESSION['CompletionDate']."</p>

mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO conservatorreport (UniqueConservatorReportRecordID,ClockID,ConservatorID,CompletionDate,ConservatorJobIdentifier,ConservatorReportFile) VALUES ('$_SESSION[UniqueConservatorReportRecordID]','$_SESSION[UniqueClockRecordID]','$_SESSION[UniqueConservatorRecordID]',STR_TO_DATE($_SESSION[CompletionDate],'%Y-%m-%d'),'$_SESSION[ConservatorJobIdentifier]','$_SESSION[ConservatorReportFile]')")

All these variables are inserted correctly into the conservatorreport table, apart from $_SESSION[CompletionDate] which shows up in the table as 1988-00-00. The echo script sits immediately before the INSERT statement and shows:

CompletionDate = 2012-12-12

So I am convinced I am inputting 2012-12-12. I do not understand how input 2012-12-12 becomes output 1988-00-00? In the MariaDB conservatorreport table CompletionDate is defined as date.
When I leave out the STR_TO_DATE function and submit the INSERT command as follows:
mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO conservatorreport (UniqueConservatorReportRecordID,ClockID,ConservatorID,CompletionDate,ConservatorJobIdentifier,ConservatorReportFile) VALUES ('$_SESSION[UniqueConservatorReportRecordID]','$_SESSION[UniqueClockRecordID]','$_SESSION[UniqueConservatorRecordID]',$_SESSION[CompletionDate],'$_SESSION[ConservatorJobIdentifier]','$_SESSION[ConservatorReportFile]')")

I get the following error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect date value: '1988' for column conservatorreport.CompletionDate

I spent several days trying to find the bug and begin to believe it is something in the MariaDB which causes this, but I do not know where to look.
My database server details are:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
My web server details are:
Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.4
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 8.2.4## Heading ##

first of all: you are widely open to sql injections. You should use parametrised statements and not build the query by string concatenation. Secondly, you don't need str_to_date to insert a date but if you go on with building the query this way the date value should be wrap in single quotes (it's a string)

"I spent several days trying to find the bug" Simply echoing the query would have made it obvious that quotes were missing.

Yes, please use parametrized statements, always. Solemnly swear to yourself to never write code like this again.  And perhaps, think a bit about the length of your code lines? Roughly 80 to 100 characters should be the limit.

2012-12-12 (no quote chars) is an arithmetic expression. Its value is 1988. And, when you save this into DATE column then you see '1988-00-00'.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement
